# Convert array of one struct into Vector of another struct, using std::copy

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to copy an array of one class (B) (C-legacy interface) into a vector of another class (A) using std::copy.
This works fine, when A provides a constructor with parameter B, see following code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct B
{
};

struct A
{
    A(){}

    #if 1
    A(const B& b)
    {
        // constructor converting B into A
    }
    #endif
};

A toA(const B& b)
{
    A rc;
    //free function converting B into A
    return rc;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<A> VecA;
    B* arrayB;
    size_t elementsOfB;

    //here fill array B and elmentsOfB in C legacy code - does not matter for minimum example

    //now copy array of B into vector of A
    std::copy(arrayB, arrayB + elementsOfB, std::back_inserter(VecA));

    return 0;
}
```

The example is also available as [Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c09a9b8bbf7e9b3e).

I'd like to remove the converting constructor, instead I want to use the free function "toA". Of course, this does not compile (try "#if 0" in the struct definition of A), because std::copy wants to have a direct function to do this.

Is there any way to use std::copy with a free function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As its name indicates, `std::copy` is for copying objects from one place to another. That is the reason it does not provide a transforming interface.

When a transformation from one type to another is required, the [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) should be used. This allows you to provide a unary operation to implement the transformation from objects of one type to the other:

```
std::transform(arrayB, arrayB + elementsOfB, std::back_inserter(VecA), toA);
```

---

**[Working example](http://ideone.com/mjfipP)**:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct B {};
struct A {};

A toA(const B&) { 
    std::cout << "B ==> A\n";
    return A(); 
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> vecA;
    B arrayB[10];
    std::transform(arrayB, arrayB + 10, std::back_inserter(vecA), toA);
}
```